# CUDA Programming modify blockIdx.x index

Tags: arrays, cuda

```
__global__ void add( int *a, int *b, int *c ) {
int tid = blockIdx.x; // handle the data at this index if (tid < N)
}
c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];

kernel<<<6,1>>> // 6 blocks running the GPU.
```

The code above is a basic summation of 2 vectors. But I'd like to modify indexes of the arrays that are being added.
For example,
If I have my first array A = [1,2,3,4,5,6] and B = [10,20,30,40,50,60].
I'd like to have array C = [ 1+60, 2+50, 3+40, 4+30, 5+20, 6+10  ] using the elements of A and B.
blockIdx.x is increased automatically by 1, it seems, so I am not sure how to modify it.

Comment: Post actual code instead of something resembling it. And also, don't spam tags, this has little to do with c++/c in a sense. BTW pass in the array length

Comment: Please read the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/), especially chapter 2. In short: You cannot modify `blockIdx` nor `threadIdx` or similar variables. They are a unique combination for every thread.

Answer (score 1):

As Shadow said, each thread is assigned its own `threadIdx`, `blockDim`, `blockIdx`, and `gridDim` values. You cannot modify them.

For your example, you can use `gridDim.x` to get the number of blocks like this. ([full code](https://github.com/nglee/so_answers/blob/master/cuda/170518/kernel.cu))

```
__global__ void add(const int *a, const int *b, int *c)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x;
    c[tid] = a[tid] + b[(gridDim.x - 1)- tid];
}
```

To ensure that `tid` stays in array boundary, you can pass the number of array elements as an argument.

```
__global__ void add(const int *a, const int *b, int *c, const int N)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x;
    if (tid < N)
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[(gridDim.x - 1)- tid];
}
```

If you launch this kernel like `add<<<6, 1>>>(a, b, c, 6)`, then `if (tid < N)` is redundant because you're only launching 6 blocks anyway. But in general case you'll launch multiple blocks, where each block has multiple threads and there might be some padding threads in the last block.

```
unsigned int N = 1000; // total number of elements
dim3 blkDim{ 32 };
dim3 grdDim{ (N + 32 - 1) / 32 };
add<<<grdDim, blkDim>>>(a, b, c, N);
```

In this case, you have to check for boundary condition of array index.

```
__global__ void add(const int *a, const int *b, int *c, const int N)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < N)
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[(N - 1)- tid];
}
```

Comment: In the very specific case this answer is valid but you should at least mention that e.g. padding may be a problem. Passing the array size the way to go (as Passer By already mentioned).

Comment: Nice. I appreciate that you took time to edit your answer. (Btw the downvote was not mine. So I cannot push you to "+1")